# Trying to submit spark application in local model ,getting below error ''Cannot load main class from JAR"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to submit a spark application in my local and I am getting below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$1.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

below command I am using to submit the spark application

spark-submit word_count.py

Not sure what I'm missing exactly, any help would be appreciated

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

def main():
    sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Word Count").getOrCreate()
    sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    readStream = sparkSession.readStream.format('text').load(path)

    print("-------------------------------------------------")  
    print("Streaming source ready: ", readStream.isStreaming)
    readStream.printSchema()

    words = readStream.select(explode(split(readStream.value,'  ')).alias('word'))
    wordCounts = words.groupBy('word').count().orderBy('count')

    query = wordCounts.writeStream.outputMode('complete').format('console').start().awaitTermination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: did you try passing master to command `spark-submit --master local word-count.py`

Comment: Yes @undefined_variable,I tried spark-submit --master local word-count.py, still getting the same error

Comment: you need to use --py-files command line argument for passing in py file I believe. I have never used python on spark. On the other note , do you build a JAR file that would have your python file ?

Comment: I tried --py-files argument, still facing the same error, I didn't build JAR for .py file